# Sorting a large number of tuples by the first element

Tags: python

I have a large number of tuples in this format:

```
(count, (r, g, b))
```

How do I go about sorting them by their first element, the `count` value?

Comment: `tuples.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])`?

Comment: Why not just `tuples.sort()`?

Answer (score -2):

You could use the sorted function, that returns a list, and itemgetter:

```
from operator import itemgetter
lst = [(count, (r, g, b)), ...]
sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Comment: I forgot to add ```key=``` for the key argument. Now it should work properly.